# How can I set #define right after change define in script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I have a test code below.

```
IEnumerator Temp2()
{
    string _strDefine = "test";

    PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Android, 
    _strDefine);

    #if test
    Debug.Log("???");
    #endif

    yield break;
}
```

The result is that if Define 'test' was not defined before, log ??? does not show.

I want define "test" to be set right after setting define.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible the way you think of it.

After changing the `ScriptingDefineSymbols` the code has to be recompiled by Unity.

So until it is recompiled you will never see the codeblock wrapped in `#if test` pre-processors.

→ You will never see the effects of changes in the `ScriptingDefineSymbols` *right after* the change before recompilation.

Answer (score 1):

*EDITED AFTER DER HUGO COMMENT*
You can change define symbols via scripts using [PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup.html)

```
PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone, "test");
```

But then you need re compile the code (as stated previously in derHugo answer), so it won't work at the first runtime.

Anyway if you trying to do that you're using define symbols for something that was not intended. You should use a bool for your logic.

---

If you still want to change the define settings you can do that in the **editor**.

Consider also that changing them in the editor will compile the script automatically (unless you told explicitly the editor to not do that)

Edit -> Project Settings -> Player Settings.

From there you add `test` into Scripting Define Symbols.

[image]

Comment: Just updated the answer to change them via scripts.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. OP is already using this. The problem lies rather in the fact the the code has to be recompiled after changing the global defines in order to make the wrapped codeblock be executed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Removed the wrong part of the answer.